# My CardView XML doesn't show itself

Tags: android, xml

I used a tutorial for cardView and RecyclerView from Androidhive, but cardview's XML doesn't show itself...

my activity_main and content_main are visible but my cardview is invisible...

how can i fix it ?

this is my cardview xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/count"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/overflow"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/bandar_homa" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my content_main :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ir.homa.HomaActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_homa">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/love_music"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/backdrop_title"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/backdrop_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_subtitle" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/viewBg"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="ir.homa.HomaActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_homa">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is my activity_main :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

  <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_homa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_homa"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_homa_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

UPDATE:

MainActivity:

```
    package ir.homa;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;

public class HomaActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private HotelListAdapter adapter;
    private List<HotelList> hotelList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homa);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            initCollapsingToolbar();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);




    }

    private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

        // hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.shoar));
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
            private void prepareHotels() {
                int[] covers = new int[]{
                        R.mipmap.bandar_homa,
                        R.mipmap.mashhad_homa,
                        R.mipmap.shiraz_homa,
                };
                HotelList a = new HotelList("هتل هما - بندر عباس", 13, covers[0]);
                hotelList.add(a);

                a = new HotelList("هتل هما - مشهد", 8, covers[1]);
                hotelList.add(a);

                a = new HotelList("هتل هما - شیراز", 11, covers[2]);
                hotelList.add(a);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            /**
             * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
             */
            public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

                private int spanCount;
                private int spacing;
                private boolean includeEdge;

                public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
                    this.spanCount = spanCount;
                    this.spacing = spacing;
                    this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
                }
                @Override
                public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
                    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
                    int column = position % spanCount; // item column

                    if (includeEdge) {
                        outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                        outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                        if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                            outRect.top = spacing;
                        }
                        outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
                    } else {
                        outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                        outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                        if (position >= spanCount) {
                            outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    /**
     * Converting dp to pixel
     */
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homa, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(HomaActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomaActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

HotelListAdapter:

```
package ir.homa;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by SMQ on 7/3/2016.
 */
public class HotelListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HotelListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<HotelList> hotelList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
        }
    }


    public HotelListAdapter(Context mContext, List<HotelList> hotelList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.hotelList = hotelList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.hotel_list, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        HotelList hotel = hotelList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(hotel.getName());
        holder.count.setText(hotel.getNumOfRooms() + " اتاق");

        // loading hotel cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(hotel.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
     */
    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.hotel_list_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }


    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
        }

        @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_add_favourite:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "افزودن به علاقه مندی ها", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_hotel_next:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "هتل بعدی", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return hotelList.size();
    }
}
```

HotelList:

```
 package ir.homa;

    /**
     * Created by SMQ on 7/3/2016.
     */

public class HotelList {
    private String name;
    private int numOfRooms;
    private int thumbnail;

    public HotelList() {
    }

    public HotelList(String name, int numOfRooms, int thumbnail) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numOfRooms = numOfRooms;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getNumOfRooms() {
        return numOfRooms;
    }

    public void setNumOfRooms(int numOfRooms) {
        this.numOfRooms = numOfRooms;
    }

    public int getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }
    }
```

I set tools:context for this but it doesn't work yet...

Comment: Please show your Java code, and how you inflate (show) the cardview layout.

Comment: Did you create the adapter? please attach your code.

Comment: I attached all .. please review again! <3

Comment: R.layout.hotallist is your cardview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will never showed up, bcz you forget to add some line in you mainActivity.

put this line in onCreate:

```
    prepareHotels();
    adapter= new HotelListAdapter(getApplicationContext, hotelList);
    recycleview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: yeah... it should be working, bcz your whole code is fine.. you just missing some line